# Welcome message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to greet users on the server but nothing works.

This my code:

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
       await client.get_channel(918604938085548064).send(f"{member.name} has joined")
```

I also tried code like this:

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        # check if the guild the member is joining is equal to your guild's id 
        if member.guild.id != GUILD ID:
            return
        # if it's the same guild id, it continues
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x6c5ce7)
        # etc, other code
```

I thought that this code was enough, but I never received a message or an error in the console.

Console output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any message or an error then it's probably happening because you didn't enable **Privileged Gateway intents** and your bot doesn't get the member. As you can see in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) - `on_member_join` requires [`intents.Members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents%20members#discord.Intents.members).

Enable `Server Members Intent` on the [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications) site in the **Bot** section.

[image: discord site screenshot]

Then, add something like this to your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```