# How to know which servers are the bot in on discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Hi I would know how to know the servers that the bot are in like with the name and members
thanks for any helper !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through `client.guilds` / `bot.guilds` - all servers that your bot is in are stored here and get a `guild` object.

Example command that prints all server's names:

```py
@client.command()
async def server_info(ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.name) # prints all server's names
```

You can later use guild object to get members, icons, etc.

```py
@client.command()
async def server_info(ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(f"Server: {guild.name}")
        print(f"Members count: {len(guild.members)}") # counts all members
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member) # prints all members names one by one
```

***Getting members requires [`intents.members`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296711/14048071).***

Comment: it spam just :
`1
name of the bot

1

name of the bot

1

name of the bot
`

Comment: If it prints only the bot's name that means you didn't enable `intents.members`. I edited my answer showing an example of how to enable it.

Comment: thanks it worked but it doesnt show the server names it show just users

Comment: Yeah, I didn't add it in second example, but you can just add `print(guild.name)` above `print(len(guild.members))`.

Comment: okay thx i try now !

Comment: hi I tried it and it stills give me the users

Comment: I edited the second code it has to work.

Comment: okay thx i try !

Answer (score 0):

`bot.guilds`, bot being your [Bot Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) will return a list of [Guild Objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Guild), you can iterate over that and use the attributes of the guild object, for example: `guild.name`, `guild.members` (requires Member intents), and so on.